# Syntax error on token ">=", delete this token

Tags: java, boolean, syntax-error, logical-operators

This is my second practice question, but I get an error:

```
The operator || is undefined for the argument type(s) boolean, int
    Syntax error on token ">=", delete this token
```

Can anybody tell me why this is wrong?

```
package Hoofdstuk2;

public class Oefenopgave4 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int x = 55;
        int y = 44;

        boolean eerste = x < y && x >= 55;
        boolean tweede = x <= 55 || >= 44;
        boolean derde = x <= 55 ^ y >= 44;
        boolean vierde = ! (x > y);

        String output;
        output = "Eerste = " + eerste +  "Tweede = " + tweede + "Derde = " + derde + "Vierde = " + vierde;
        System.out.println(output);
    }

}
```

Comment: btw `x <= 55 ^ y >= 44;` is the same as `x <= (55 ^ y) >= 44;`  as ^ has higher precedence. The compiler doesn't what you meant to say.

Answer (score 3):

```
boolean tweede = x <= 55 || >= 44;
```

What are you trying to accomplish? You meant to write:

```
boolean tweede = x <= 55 || x >= 44;
```

Mind the `x`. Now it compiles, and execution yields:

> `Eerste = falseTweede = trueDerde = falseVierde = false`

Also take note of what Peter Lawrey said in the comment if you are wondering about the output.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the variable to be compared in the condition

the same syntax you did for the 1st variable:

```
boolean eerste = x < y && x >= 55;
```

mus be done for the second.

```
boolean tweede = x <= 55 || >= 44; // you are missing the x i guess in x>=44
```